# Chrome Extension Devs - What is the cleanest way for me to scrape data from another page without leaving Gmail?

Tags: web-scraping, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools, inboxsdk

I am building a Gmail sales data tool where:

1. You open the compose box in Gmail
2. When you compose a message to john@example.com, it scrapes example.com's content & lists it in the compose box (so you have stuff to talk about/context of the company)

Similar tools include Lavender AI & Regie AI.

I cannot for the life of me figure out how to do this.

My current setup is a messy, god-awful Apify API call after a Puppeteer script executes (i fetch the data & it gets put in the compose box)

But this is insanely slow.

What can I do?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.